# Comparing filenames and adding them in a list in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of filenames called "allCsvFiles". On the other hand I have a '.txt' file which in every line holds an ID of a bacteria. I want to compare the name of each file in "allCsvFiles" to each line of this '.txt' file. If the names are equal I want to add the '.csv' filename in another list called "allGeneralFiles". this is my code:

```
      for f in allCsvFiles:
         with  open(idsFile) as generalIdsFIle:
              for line in generalIdsFIle:
                  if f[ :-3] == line:
                      allGeneralFiles.append(f)
      print(*allGeneralFiles, sep = ' , ')
```

The problem is that after I run it on terminal, i do not get any error but just an empty line without any record. I know that the list should not be empty.
Thank you!

Comment: `line` also contains the trailing newline character.

Comment: Why don't you print out the intermediate values to see if what you expected to happen is actually happening, or use a debugger?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Assuming `f` is something like `myfile.csv`, `f[:-3]` will be `myfile.` (with a period at the end.)  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging? Please provide a [mcve], and see [ask], [help/on-topic]. As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, unless there is a good reason not to do so.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you! the problem was that I was comparing every line with myfile. what I did to improve was : if f[ :-4] == line.strip():

Answer (score 0):

It looks like line in genralIdsFIle does not match with your filename. Stripping the beginning and ending new lines and spaces from the line before comparing it with the file name may be a solution.

Try this:

```
  for f in allCsvFiles:
      with  open(idsFile) as generalIdsFIle:
          for line in generalIdsFIle:
              if f[ :-3] == line.strip():
                  allGeneralFiles.append(f)
  print(*allGeneralFiles, sep = ' , ')
```